# Manejo de cadenas en python

Tags: python

Saludos tengo el siguiente código:

```
def abs_string(string):
    if string.startswith('-'):
        return string[1:]
    return string
```

el cual funciona bien, es decir le envio como parametro un **string**  si el mismo contiene un guion medio lo retira y retorna solo el **string**.

bien ahora mi duda dentro del codigo posee lo siguiente:

```
string[1:]
```

que quiere decir este número que va dentro de los corchetes o como se denomina eso en python gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ese [1:] significa que va a devolver la palabra de izquierda a derecha , si pudiera [-1:] devuelve la palabra al revés

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El número representa  simplemente el índice del carácter en la cadena. Una cadena (`str`) al igual que una lista (`lista`), una tupla (`tuple`) o una cadena de bytes (`bytes`) es un conjunto de elementos ordenados (caracteres UTF-8) e indizables. Cada elemento es numerado empezando desde 0:

> ```
> cadena:  HOLA
> indices: 0123
> ```

de forma que puedes acceder a un carácter dado usando su índice y la sintaxis `objeto[indice]`:

```
>>> cadena = "Hola"
>>> cadena[0]
'H'
>>> cadena[2]
'l'
```

Python además permite usar índices negativos, de forma que -1 hace referencia al último elemento, -2 el antepenúltimo, etc:

```
>>> cadena = "Hola"
>>> cadena[-1]
'a'
>>> cadena[-2]
'l'
```

Por otro lado, la sintaxis que observas (`[1:]`) se conoce como indizado extendido y lleva a cabo un slicing o rebanado del iterable, el cuál permite obtener una **nueva** cadena con el contenido de parte de la cadena original (o toda como veremos al final). Es decir, en vez de obtener un solo carácter usando su índice, obtenemos un conjunto de caracteres de la cadena usando un rango de índices. La sintaxis general es:

```
[indice_inicial : indice_final : paso]
```

- El indice inicial indica a partir de cual elemento comienza el corte. Si no se indica nada se asume que el corte se inicia desde el primer elemento.
- El índice final indica el  índice del elemento final del corte, el cual **no es incluido** en el mismo. Si no se indica nada se asume que es hasta el último elemento (incluido).
- El paso indica cuantos indice contamos hasta incluir un nuevo elemento. Por ejemplo `[::3]` toma uno de cada tres elementos desde el principio al final de la lista. Si no se indica nada es 1 por defecto (tomar los elementos de uno en uno desde el indice inicial hasta el final). El concepto es realmente el mismo que en `range`, se empieza por el índice inicial del slice y  en cada "iteración" el siguiente índice se genera sumando el paso al anterior índice:

  > slice = [4:8:2]
  >   primer indice = 4
  >   segundo indice = 4 + 2 = 6
  >   tercer indice = 6 + 2 = 8  Es igual al indice final, no se incluye
  >
  > slice = [-2:-9:-2]
  >   primer indice = -2
  >   segundo indice = -2 + -2 = -4
  >   tercer indice = -4 + -2 = -6
  >   cuarto_indice = -6 + - 2 = -8
  >   quinto_indice = -8 + -2  = -10 Supera al indice final, no se incluye.

  Dada la posibilidad de usar indices positivos y negativos como límites del slice, todo se complica un poco. Quizás sea el argumento más complicado de entender y de explicar, más abajo hay algunos ejemplos.

Los tres argumentos han de ser enteros.

Obviamente hace falta al menos un `:` para realizar un slicing, de lo contrario solo hacemos un indizado sobre un elemento. El segundo `:`, el que separa el indice final del paso, es opcional, si no determinamos un paso no es necesario.

Por lo tanto, en tu caso `[1:]` indica que se haga un corte de la cadena original empezando desde el elemento con índice 1 (el segundo  carácter ya que el indizado empieza en 0) hasta el final de la cadena. Con ello consigues una nueva cadena sin el `-`, que es el primer carácter y con índice 0 por tanto:

```
cadena = "-999999"
```

> ```
> cadena:       - 9 9 9 9 9 9
> indices:      0 1 2 3 4 5 6
> cadena [1:]:  -|9 9 9 9 9 9|
> indices [1:]: 0|1 2 3 4 5 6|
> ```

Algunos ejemplos de rebanado:

> ```
> >>> cad = "StackOverflow"
>
> # Todos los caracteres desde el segundo
> >>> cad[1:] 
> 'tackOverflow'
>
> # Caracteres desde el segundo al quinto
> >>> cad[1:5] 
> 'tack'
>
> # Caracteres desde cuarto contando desde el final hasta el penúltimo
> >>> cad[-4:-2] 
> 'fl'
>
> # Desde el inicio de la cadena hasta el quinto carácter.
> >>> cad[:5]
> 'Stack'
>
> # Toda la cadena (copia superficial o shallow  copy)
> >>> cad[:]   
> 'StackOverflow'
>
> # Desde el segundo carácter hasta el sexto tomados cada dos caracteres
> >>> cad[1:6:2]
> 'tcO'
>
> # Cada tres caracteres
> >>> cad[::3]
> 'Scvfw'
>
> # Todos los caracteres pero tomados desde el final (revierte la cadena)
> >>> cad[::-1]
> 'wolfrevOkcatS'
>
> # Desde el penúltimo carácter hasta el tercero tomando cada dos
> >>> cad[-2:1:-2]       
> 'ofeOc'
>
> # Desde el quinto carácter hasta el inicio de la cadena
> >>> cad[5::-1])
> 'OkcatS'
> ```

A diferencia del indexado simple, no se produce un `IndexError` si hay indices inválidos en el rango del rebanado:

> ```
> >>> cad = "StackOverflow"
> >>> cad[5:100]
> 'Overflow'
> >>> cad[100:150]
> ''
> ```

El método que permite usar indizado y slicing sobre un objeto es [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), el cual podemos implementar en clases propias si queremos dar soporte a los mismos.

Esta sintaxis es común a cualquier otro objeto que soporte indizado, como listas, tuplas, etc. En objetos mutables como las listas tienen algunas aplicaciones extra, por ejemplo podemos eliminar  parte de los elementos una lista con `del` o realizar asignaciones:

> ```
> >>> l = [7, 8, 6, 1, 5]      
> >>> del l[::2]
> >>> l
> [8, 1]
>
> >>> l = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> >>> l[1:3] = [1, 2]
> >>> l
> [0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
> ```

Otra forma de realizar rebanados es creando directamente objetos `Slice` mediante el builtin [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). `cad[:7:2]` es realmente traducido a `slice(None, 7,2)`:

> ```
> >>> s = slice(None, 7, 2)
> >>> cad = "StackOverflow"
> >>> cad[s]
> Sakv
> ```

además de su uso interno, los objetos `Slice` son muy importantes en librerías que trabajan con arrays y matrices como NumPy, Pandas, etc

---

Por cierto, si quieres eliminar todos los posibles caracteres `"-"` que existan al inicio de la cadena, puedes hacer uso de `str.lstrip()`:

> ```
> >>> cad = "-123456"
> >>> cad.lstrip("-")
> 123456
> >>> cad = "---123456"
> >>> cad.lstrip("-")
> 123456
> >>> cad = "123456"
> >>> cad.lstrip("-")
> 123456
> ```

Comment: genial excelente explicación..!!

Comment: ¡Buena! Aunque tienes un typo, el término correcto es "Shallow copy". Creo que "Shadow copy" puede confundir la interpretación.

Answer (score 2):

[En este enlace](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings) podrás encontrar una documentación amplia (en inglés) donde se explica detalladamente cada utilidad de la función `string` y `substring`.

Para ser preciso el texto dentro de los corchetes se llama `String slice` y lo que hace es referiste a la fracción de texto que le indiques dentro de una cadena de texto, teniendo en cuenta que se escribe de la siguiente forma:

```
variable[inicio:fin]
```

Te invito a leer el artículo para que veas muchos más usos de los `String slices` dentro de python, como por ejemplo valores reversos (`variable[-4]`), ejemplo de la documentación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que sea de ayuda.